# How to add Filter dropdown by Categories

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image: My soucre code]

I want filter by Categories dropdown like combobox

Comment: Please post your source code, not a screenshot of your source code. You can add a snippet directly so we can take a look at what you have tried so far. Have you tried anything?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vanxay588/pen/yLbxMKW

Comment: You should update your question with the code instead of leaving the screenshot. Klick edit. You should also copy&paste the code here instead of linking to the code.